# Resource temporarily unavailable - TCP 5985

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, terraform

I cloned a git repo from a Udemy course, changed the access key and the secret key, the ami but I am still getting an error message like this: dial tcp 35.158.225.227:5985: connect: resource temporarily unavailable.

The ec2 instance state is running but the powershell can't be executed. Do you have an idea about whats not working properly?

windows-instance.tf

```
resource "aws_key_pair" "mykey" {
  key_name = "mykey"
  public_key = "${file("${var.PATH_TO_PUBLIC_KEY}")}"
}

resource "aws_instance" "win-example" {
  ami = "${lookup(var.WIN_AMIS, var.AWS_REGION)}"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  key_name = "${aws_key_pair.mykey.key_name}"
  user_data = <<EOF
<powershell>
net user ${var.INSTANCE_USERNAME} '${var.INSTANCE_PASSWORD}' /add /y
net localgroup administrators ${var.INSTANCE_USERNAME} /add
winrm quickconfig -q
winrm set winrm/config/winrs '@{MaxMemoryPerShellMB="300"}'
winrm set winrm/config '@{MaxTimeoutms="1800000"}'
winrm set winrm/config/service '@{AllowUnencrypted="true"}'
winrm set winrm/config/service/auth '@{Basic="true"}'
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="WinRM 5985" protocol=TCP dir=in localport=5985 action=allow
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="WinRM 5986" protocol=TCP dir=in localport=5986 action=allow
net stop winrm
sc.exe config winrm start=auto
net start winrm
</powershell>
EOF

  provisioner "file" {
    source = "test.txt"
    destination = "C:/test.txt"
  }
  connection {
    type = "winrm"
    timeout = "10m"
    user = "${var.INSTANCE_USERNAME}"
    password = "${var.INSTANCE_PASSWORD}"
  }
}
```

vars.tf

```
variable "AWS_ACCESS_KEY" {}
variable "AWS_SECRET_KEY" {}
variable "AWS_REGION" {
  default = "eu-central-1"
}
variable "WIN_AMIS" {
  type = "map"
  default = {
    eu-central-1 = "ami-6af7f381"
    eu-west-1 = "ami-96e1f27c"
  }
}

variable "PATH_TO_PRIVATE_KEY" {
  default = "mykey"
}
variable "PATH_TO_PUBLIC_KEY" {
  default = "mykey.pub"
}
variable "INSTANCE_USERNAME" {
  default = "Terraform"
}
variable "INSTANCE_PASSWORD" { }
```

provider.tf

```
provider "aws" {
    access_key = "${var.AWS_ACCESS_KEY}"
    secret_key = "${var.AWS_SECRET_KEY}"
    region = "${var.AWS_REGION}"
}
```

I also have in the folder a terraform.tfvars, pub and a pem file. What am I doing wrong?

Best regards

Comment: Your instance doesn't appear to have a security group defined so it's probably picking up the default security group for the VPC. Instead you should add a security group to the instance that allows inbound traffic on TCP/5985 and TCP/5986.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are not logging in as the Windows Administrator.
You are trying to log in as a user that doesn't exist and then add that user to the system.  That can't be done.  You have to log in as Administrator.

To do that change

```
key_name = "${aws_key_pair.mykey.key_name}"
```

to

```
key_name = "${aws_key_pair.mykey.key_name}"
get_password_data = true
```

The new line

```
get_password_data = true
```

tells Terraform to get the Windows Administrator password as soon as it's created.  Once the password is created you need to access it, decrypt it and then use it to log in to the instance.  So, next change..

```
connection {
  type = "winrm"
  timeout = "10m"
  user = "${var.INSTANCE_USERNAME}"
  password = "${var.INSTANCE_PASSWORD}"
}
```

to

```
connection {
  type = "winrm"
  timeout = "10m"
  password = "${rsadecrypt(self.password_data, file("${var.PATH_TO_PRIVATE_KEY}"))}"
```

}

This will log you in as Administrator using the decrypted Administrator password.

Next remove,

```
net user ${var.INSTANCE_USERNAME} '${var.INSTANCE_PASSWORD}' /add /y
net localgroup administrators ${var.INSTANCE_USERNAME} /add
```

This isn't needed because you'll be logging in as Administrator with access to the password.

Also change

```
winrm quickconfig -q
```

to

```
winrm quickconfig -force
```

Lastly, from vars.tf remove

```
variable "INSTANCE_USERNAME" {
  default = "Terraform"
}
variable "INSTANCE_PASSWORD" { }
```

because you'll be logged in as Administrator instead.

Everything should then work fine.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!